# Not able to render a React element in React-BootStrap-Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I want to render buttons in react-bootstrap-table. However, If I pass a React component as the content, the table is render with `[object Object]`.

Here's the code I've tried so far:

```
// Imports
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from "react-bootstrap-table";
import "../../../node_modules/react-bootstrap-table/css/react-bootstrap-table.css";

// Exports
export default class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Defaults
    this.props.options.search = this.props.options.search ? true : false;
    this.props.options.pagination = this.props.options.pagination ? true : false;
  }

  // Option Buttons
  optionButtons = (cell, row) => {
    return cell.map(item => {
      let key = Object.keys(item)[0];
      return (
        <Link to={item[key]} className="btn btn-sm">
          {key}
        </Link>
      );
    });
  };

  // This works however
  // optionButtons = (cell, row) => {
  //   return <Link to="/some/route" className="btn btn-sm">Action</Link>;
  // };

  render() {
    let headings = this.props.columns.map((heading, index) => {
      let key = Object.keys(heading)[0];
      if (index === 0) {
        return (
          <TableHeaderColumn
            key={heading[key]}
            dataSort={heading.sortable ? true : false}
            dataField={key}
            width={
              heading.width && !isNaN(heading.width)
                ? heading.width.toString()
                : null
            }
            isKey
          >
            {heading[key]}
          </TableHeaderColumn>
        );
      }
      if (key === "options") {
        return (
          <TableHeaderColumn
            key={heading[key]}
            dataFormat={this.optionButtons}
            dataField={key}
            width={
              heading.width && !isNaN(heading.width)
                ? heading.width.toString()
                : null
            }
          >
            {heading[key]}
          </TableHeaderColumn>
        );
      }
      return (
        <TableHeaderColumn
          key={heading[key]}
          dataSort={heading.sortable ? true : false}
          dataField={key}
          width={
            heading.width && !isNaN(heading.width)
              ? heading.width.toString()
              : null
          }
        >
          {heading[key]}
        </TableHeaderColumn>
      );
    });

    return (
      <BootstrapTable
        data={this.props.data}
        search={this.props.options.search}
        pagination={this.props.options.pagination}
      >
        {headings}
      </BootstrapTable>
    );
  }
}
```

The data I am passing to the `options` key is an array with multiple objects. The problem is in rendering the option buttons. The idea is to be able to pass the number of buttons/link I want from a component and they will be rendered.

This is the data being passed to the `options` key:

```
options: [
  { Edit: `/item/${item.id}/edit` },
  { Delete: `/item/${item.id}/delete` }
]
```

Comment: @Yurii please add your comment as an answer. Although, I am reading this after I figured it out :D Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Ajay did you get solution. if yes please share.

Comment: @RaviSaxena I don't really remember, it was like 2 years ago. But I'll take a look at the code and get back to you.

Comment: i got solution. Below answer is correct. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `dataFormat` expects a single value, wrap your buttons into a root element (`div` for example), or into a [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) if supported.